# ViewPager where each view shares the same ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

** Current Situation: **

One Activity, with one ListView, that changes its contents based on resetting the adapter    between   three different adapters.  There is just one ListView with id : list.  Thats it. When I reset adapter it adjusts the content of the list view.

What I want to do:

Use ViewPager to page between the different list instantiations.

Problem: View pager seems to be setup to take separate layouts, but I have written all my logic against a single list. It would be a big rewrite to use three different ListViews pointing to differnt list.

Question:  How do I use the ViewPager to switch between views of the same list that are generated by different adapters being applied to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same fragment for every page. Set a single variable in the intent that tells the fragment which adapter should be used. Technically it's not the same listview, although it is the same code (which is what usually matters I think).

I don't think it's possible for it to technically be the same listview considering the swiping animation.

Comment: Agreed it cannot be the same listview, since different data must appear at same time.  Could you clarify how Fragment would be used with a ViewPager.